# Adding more than three recipients to an email in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

How do I add more than three (3) recipients to an email in Thunderbird?

[image: to section of new email]

I can't imagine that 3 is the maximum number.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply add them as a list, seperated with commas:

```
rec1@example.com, rec2@example.com, rec3@example.com, "John Doe" <rec4@example.com>
```

Comment: Note that all recipients will be able to see the e-mail addresses of everyone else, with both this and Mike's solution.

Answer (score 54):

Just keep hitting enter after each one, and it should give you more spaces for extra entries (tested on Thunderbird 3.1.11). Note the difference in the scrollbars on each image, taken from a single email to be sent:

[image]

[image]

Commas work, too, as @trurl said already.

Comment: Addressbook lookups don't seem to work if you use commas. This does.

Answer (score 13):

Hover your mouse over the bar between the subject line and your email, and stretch the pane downwards.  You can see more emails that way.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/bcni1.jpg]

Answer (score 4):

You can also create a Distribution List/Mailing List, assuming the recipients are in your Address Book. If so, follow these instructions:

1. Click on "Address Book"
2. Click on "New List"
3. Give your list a name (e.g. My Friends)
4. Then type in the e-mail addresses of all of your recipients and click "OK".

Then when you want to send an e-mail to these recipients, just type in "My Friends" and compose your message and then send, and voilà, simple as that!